# How to get a collection of emails beginning with the subject line "RE:" in Outlook using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, outlook-addin

Extreme novice with C# here. I'm attempting to get a count for the number of emails that have a subject line that begins with "RE:" that were sent to me within the last month. For example something like below but instead of restricting to emails that only have "RE:" as the subject, I'd like to restrict only to emails that have a subject line beginning with "RE:"  and that have a sent date within the last month. Any help would be much much appreciated. Thank you!

```
Outlook.Items repliedItems = inbox.Items.Restrict(@"[Subject] = ""RE:""");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DASL queries with the `ci_startswith` or `ci_phrasematch` operators. For example, the following query performs a phrase match query for `RE:` in the message subject:

```
filter = "@SQL=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0037001E\" ci_phrasematch 'RE:'"
```

Also you'd need to combine another search criteria to the string passed to the `Restrict` method - items were sent to me within the last month. Use the [MailItem.ReceivedTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.receivedtime) property which returns a date indicating the date and time at which the item was received. The following articles explains how to use DateTime structures for filtering items in Outlook:

- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)
- [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)